# Restarting a apache2 over perticular request in django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, webfaction

I am working a project, that creates an django app over a request. Since the webserver apache needs to be restarted to add new files created. I tried following:

1) Django request_complete Signals: This is not good way because I dont want my server to be restarting on every request complete

2) threading.Time:I tried to run a function with some delay so that it allows complete the current request.

This is not working giving following error:

```
RuntimeError at /apps/37f63340-2984-40b1-a728-1cf3d0820ae6/
threads can only be started once
```

Please suggest me way to solve this problem.

Comment: You just want to restart apache2 ? If yes, you have to do : `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this with "webfaction" so I'm going to assume you're using WebFaction's default mod_wsgi setup.

If that's the case, then you can restart the mod_wsgi daemon processes, instead of restarting Apache itself, as described in the mod_wsgi documentation: [Reloading Source Code](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/reloading-source-code.html#restarting-daemon-processes)